# Solve $\sin^2 x-1=0$ for $0^\circ\le x\le360^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am new to this so I don't know how to type the exponent. Basically, I have to solve for $x$ for the following equation

$$\sin^2 x-1=0.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/75923 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let's say that  $y=\sin(x)$. What does the value of $y$ have to be in order to satisfy your equation?

Comment: That is not mentioned.

Comment: @user152413 You are asked to mention it.

Comment: It is a hint. Try to think about it. If $y=\sin(x)$ and you know that $(\sin(x))^2 - 1 = 0$, what equation does $y$ satisfy?

Comment: are the answers 90 and 270 degrees?

Comment: Indeed. That is because $y^2=1,$ meaning that $y$ can be either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: yay! thank you. what if i replace the sin in the equation with cos.. I get 0 and 180 degrees? are those correct?

Comment: Indeed they are.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $$\sin^2x-1=(\sin x-1)(\sin x+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2x=1\iff\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=-1=\cos180^\circ$$

$$\iff2x=(2n+1)180^\circ\iff x=(2n+1)90^\circ$$ where $n$ is any integer

Find suitable values of $n$ from the given condition